# i need to display the corresponding data of the barcode from user input

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, arraylist

this program is easy but i can't seem to understand it ><

so the user have to write a barcode in the first textbox, and the product on the second textbox, and then save those two to the arraylist after clicking the add button. then the next section is the search bar, wherein the user searches for the barcode and the label below that searchbox should display the barcode's corresponding product.

i think there is a mistake from my foreach statements or so. i can only display the existing data in the product textbox.

pls help

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int barcode = Convert.ToInt32(txt_barcode.Text);
            barcodeList.Add(barcode);

            string product = txt_product.Text;
            productList.Add(product);

            MessageBox.Show("saved");
        }

        private void txt_search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int barcodeSearch = Convert.ToInt32(txt_search.Text);

                    for (int count = 0; count < barcodeList.Count; count++)
                    {
                        foreach (int barcode in barcodeList)
                        {
                            if (barcodeSearch == barcode)
                            {
                                foreach (string product in productList)
                                {
                                    lbl_product.Text = "" + product;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }   
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: i don't really get what you are asking but the for probably can be deleted cause you already using foreach to loop the list, unless you have a list of barcodelist then the for would make sense

Comment: It seems that inside the foreach loop, this is unnecessary. You can use barcodeList[count] to get the barcode at the current index. If a match is found, set the label text to the corresponding product and return to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are somehow trying to retrieve an item from one unordered list based on some other unordered list. You could achieve this using indexing, but that's unwieldy, complicated and error-prone.

I would suggest using a `Dictionary`, which stores items based on a `key`, so you can easily retrieve them.

```
var productDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Adding to it:

```
productDictionary[txt_barcode.Text] = txt_product.Text;
```

And retrieving it:

```
if (productDictionary.ContainsKey(txt_search.Text)
{
    lbl_product.Text = productDictionary[txt_search.Text];
}
```

No need for looping over several lists, and you also avoid potential problems with double keys.

Note that I also removed the unnecessary conversion to `int`. If you receive a string why not store it as a string? If it needs to be an integer, you should *validate* that it is an integer, and not blindly convert it. What happens if you try to convert "123AB" or "Foo" to an `int`, and how would that affect your search results? ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you always need to validate user input before doing anything with the data.

```
int barcode = Convert.ToInt32(txt_barcode.Text);
```

This will throw an error if the user enters any non numerical value into your `TextBox`
You could do something like:

```
int barcode;
if(!Int.TryParse(txt_barcode.Text, out barcode))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid barcode!");
   return;
}
```

Keep in mind that barcode values are not always numerical thus a real world scenario would most likely ask for a string value.

I don't see a good reason to keep the `Product` and `Barcode` value separate. Create a simple class to use as your model like this:

```
public class Product
{
    string barcode;
    public string Barcode
    {
        get => barcode;
        set => barcode = value;
    }

    string product_name;
    public string ProductName
    {
        get => product_name;
        set => product_name = value;
    }
}
```

Then when you are filling in your `Collection` you can do this:

```
// This is the collection you will be storing your products in
List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string barcode = txt_barcode.Text;
    string product = txt_product.Text;

    Product myProduct = new Product()
    {
        Barcode = barcode,
        ProductName = product
    };

    Products.Add(Product); // MyCollection is of List<Product> type
}
```

And then you can search the whole thing by walking trough the list of products like this:

```
private Product SearchForProduct()
{
    foreach (Product p in Products)
    {
         // This will return the first product that matches either of the cases
        // Play around with you search logic
        if (p.Barcode == "YourSearchTerm" || p.ProductName == "YourSearchTerm")
        {
            return p; // Returns the product that matches the search terms
        }
    }

    return null; // Returns null if no product matching the search term is found
}
```

You can then call the method like this:

```
Product search_result = SearchForProduct(search_textbox.Text);
if(search_result == null)
{
  MessageBox.Show("No Product matching the search terms was found!");
  return;
}
else
{
  // Do something with the found product 
}
```