# How to check if there is a number and the letter X in a textbox in c#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, integer, point-of-sale

I'm using C# and winforms.
So I'm trying to build a POS app that has a textbox for barcodes and commands. One of the commands is "t" for total.

I want to implement another command that has a number and the letter "x" after it, for the quantity of the next item scanned or entered. Basically I want to make it so that if you put in "2x" into the textbox, it sets a variable to 2. Is there any easy way to that for any integer number. Like `if(txtbarcode.text == int + "x")` (I know this code doesn't work but it's here as an example)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.
EB.

Comment: Do you have more exemple of the string in txtbarcode? Like does it always end with a letter and have a integer before it?

Comment: Yeah so the txtbarcdoe is kind of like an address bar. I have two if statments, one for if there is ONLY a "t" (for total like I mentioned), and the other one is for an actual barcode (it searches a databse and returns some values which are added to a table)

Comment: Is it a coincidence that [multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488298/i-need-to-display-the-corresponding-data-of-the-barcode-from-user-input) pop up about barcodes in `winforms` applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems using regular expression can help in this case

Here is the snippet

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pattern = @"^(-?\d+\.?\d*)x$"; // support negatives and decimal
        var match = Regex.Match("123.31x", pattern);
        
        if(match.Success) {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); //return numbers only
        }
    }
}
```

supported cases

```
123x
-1x
123.31x
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped a ton! I just had to add ```match.Groups[1].value``` for it to work! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simple with `int.TryParse` and `EndsWith`+`TrimEnd`:

```
int? count = text.EndsWith("x") && int.TryParse(text.TrimEnd('x'), out int c) ? c : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Regex.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string text = "2x" ;
string exp = "/[0-9]/g";
string result = Regex.matches(text, exp);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output will be: 2 here

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to check if a number N is followed by the letter X in a text box then you can implement a Boolean method that captures the value in the text box as a string then converts the string to a character array then you can check if the value at index 0 is a number and the value at index 1 is the letter X.

```
public bool CorrectTextBoxInput(string text){
    if(text == string.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var arr = text.ToCharArray();
        if (Int32.TryParse(arr[0].ToString(), out var res) && arr[1] == 'x')
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like regex is your friend here:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex rx = new Regex(@"\d*x")

if(rx.IsMatch(userInput)){
   //do stuff
}
```

\d - any digit
, * - as many times as needed
, x - literal 'x'